# git review fails w/ "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists"

Tags: git, gitlab, gerrit, git-review

We've just setup gerrit in house. Some projects work, some don't. The ones that don't work fail like this:

```
git review -v
2014-02-26 11:54:57.029764 Running: git log --color=never --oneline HEAD^1..HEAD
2014-02-26 11:54:57.032894 Running: git remote
2014-02-26 11:54:57.035826 Running: git branch -a --color=never
2014-02-26 11:54:57.040726 Running: git rev-parse --show-toplevel --git-dir
2014-02-26 11:54:57.043507 Running: git remote update gerrit
Fetching gerrit
2014-02-26 11:54:58.697639 Running: git rebase -i remotes/gerrit/master
2014-02-26 11:54:58.840323 Running: git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
2014-02-26 11:54:58.850137 Running: git config --get color.ui
2014-02-26 11:54:58.854311 Running: git log --color=always --decorate --oneline HEAD --not remotes/gerrit/master --
2014-02-26 11:54:58.860093 Running: git branch --color=never
2014-02-26 11:54:58.864691 Running: git log HEAD^1..HEAD
Using local branch name "master" for the topic of the change submitted
2014-02-26 11:54:58.872208 Running: git push gerrit HEAD:refs/publish/master
fatal: One or more refs/for/ names blocks change upload
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
2014-02-26 11:55:00.029139 Running: git rev-parse --show-toplevel --git-dir
```

Contents of .gitview:

```
[gerrit]
host=gitlab.company.net
project=api/core-services.git
```

`git review -s` has been run and remotes are configured:

```
git remote -v
gerrit  ssh://me@gitlab.company.net:29418/api/core-services.git (fetch)
gerrit  ssh://me@gitlab.company.net:29418/api/core-services.git (push)
origin  git@gitlab.company.net:api/core-services.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.company.net:api/core-services.git (push)
```

The project doesn't show up in the project list (also missing from UI):

```
ssh -p 29418 gitlab.company.net gerrit ls-projects | grep core-services
(returns nothing)
```

But when I try to add the project it already exists (also fails when adding from UI):

```
ssh -p 29418 gitlab.company.net gerrit create-project api/core-services.git
fatal: project "api/core-services" exists
```

`git for-each-ref refs/for` returns nothing.

I am setup as an administrator in gerrit. I can push to origin. Currently working on master since it is a new project. No other branches. Running ubuntu 13.10, git 1.8.3.2 and git-review 1.21 locally. GitLab 6.4.3 3173626, git 1.8.4.4 and Gerrit 2.8.1 on the server. I can submit reviews on other projects.

Right now, the only common thing that I can find between the projects that don't work is that they contain a dash ("-") in the name.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Searches haven't turned up anything useful and I'm at my limit of gerrit knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the `git remote show review` telling?

Comment: (How do you format line breaks in comments?)

`git remote show gerrit

    * remote gerrit

      Fetch URL: ssh://me@gitlab.company.net:29418/api/core-services.git

      Push  URL: ssh://me@gitlab.company.net:29418/api/core-services.git

      HEAD branch: master

      Remote branch:

        master tracked

      Local ref configured for 'git push':

        master pushes to master (up to date)`

Comment: check aout this [article](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/error-change-upload-blocked.html) maybe the refs/for branch already created, so clean everything out

Comment: I did mention above that `git for-each-ref refs/for` returns nothing.

Comment: Are the projects really there, are they created? Did you check on the server if they are present?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like git review is trying to push like this

```
HEAD:refs/publish/master
```

It should push like this

```
 HEAD:refs/for/master
```